# Running SSR backup to NAS

Tags: windows, backup, symantec

I am having an issue running a SSR backup to a networked NAS. When using the backup wizard to define the new location, it does not see the drive. Any suggestions?

Just FYI, using Windows Server 2008 R2 and a Buffalo Nas Terastaion.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, simply go to Tasks > Options, then under General there is a box below "Default backup destination:" . Simply enter the path \server\share, click Apply then should be good to go.

One issue I was having was not being able to authenticate the NAS against active directory. A workaround was to authenticate against the Workgroup the NAS was in and it seemed to work fine. Backups successfully ran on all machines.

Hopefully this helps someone out.